# Testing a Dialogflow app

Tags: testing, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

Is it possible to install a Dialogflow chatbot for testing on my Google Home device 
without using the phrase "Talk to my test app?"

I am a rather new user of Dialogflow and have several simple test apps that
I plan to develop as learning exercises.  Can set them up for testing on my
personal Google Home device without entering the "Talk to my test app" and without 
submitting them for distribution to the Google Home community.  I do not consider them 
sinificant enough to offer them the the Google community at large.

I anticipate the develop of the following apps: 1 - SillyNameMaker, 2 - Woodchuck, 
Gettysburg Address.

Thanks for any help
Jim

Answer (score 3):

If you provide an app name and sample invocations in the "App information" section of the Actions on Google console, you'll be able to use this name to invoke your app on devices that are signed in to the Google account you are using for development.

One thing to note, however, is that you can only have one app in testing at a time. If you start testing a new app, the previous one (even if it is named) will be unavailable.